# Safe to freeze boiled/ blanched pork bones/ meat for future use to cook soup?

Tags: food-safety, meat, storage-method, freezing, storage-lifetime

This is relating to Asian/ Chinese style soup/ broth cooking.

I am a very busy person and do not have time to cook. I cook in a small kitchen with the basic crockeries. I usually do my groeceries during the weekend to prepare for dinner during the working days.

One of my favourite dishes are soups boiled with pork or beef and I usually boil or blanch the meat and bones with ginger/ green onion and some cooking wine before hand to get rid of any blood, gunks and pork odour/ taint before adding clean water for a clearer, cleaner and tastier broth. However, this is a very tedious process for me as I spend to much time prepping and having to slow boil the soup.

In order to save time, I was thinking of boiling/ blanching my bones and meat in one go and freezing them in portions so that i can throw them in separately the next time I cook my soup. This way I skip the hassle of defrosting, cleaning and blanching.

Does anybody do that here? Is it safe if I do that? I'm not too well versed in food safety and would love to know what you guys think. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is perfectly safe as long as the raw meat remains refrigerated until use, is boiled or blanched, chilled quickly, and then frozen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The raw meat was taken out of the freezer, sat in the fridge for 5 hours and striaght into the pot (it was still a tad bit frozen then). After boiling, I rinsed with tap water and placed it in the freezer.

Comment: *Every* time I serve a ham, I freeze the leftovers and the bone and use them later to make red beans. Been doing that for generations.